# What is the correct way to setup an independent Route that is not a part of App.js in React Router Dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create an independent Route (not sure if that's the correct term) at `BulletinBoard.js` where I can use `Link` to go to `Create Bulletin` component.
I'm also trying to create another independent Route at `BulletinList.js` where I can navigate to `Edit Bulletin` with their respective IDs.

Before this, I tried using useRouteMatch with path and url, but apparently that wasn't the correct way to do it, now I'm told to use useLocation, it does adds the `/createbulletin` and `/editbulletin/id` paths behind the current URL, but it doesn't navigate to the component itself.

I've been cracking my head over this for the past 2 days and I still haven't figured out the correct way to do this.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-pare-vhisn) is the codesandbox that I've created for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code didnt navigate to a different component after the url changed is because you didnt use the `exact` attribute when declaring the route. So its matching `/bulletinboard/anything` and then it always renders de `BulletinBoard` component.

You could define all routes at the `App.js` file like

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/bulletinboard" component={BulletinBoard} exact />
        <Route path="/bulletinboard/edit/:id" component={EditBulletinBoard} exact />
        <Route path="/infohub" component={InfoHub} exact />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Also, check out the [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook

So at the `BulletinBoard.js` when the user clicks the link

```
onClick={() => history.push(`/bulletinboard/edit/${id}`)}
```

Note that the edit route renders a different component that your codesandbox didn't have yet

Comment: Is it possible to pass a function as prop through this method? For example, in my current ```BulletinBoard.js```, I'm passing onAdd function as a prop to get the value from the child (AddBulletin.js) back to the parent (BulletinBoard.js).

```<Route path={`${path}/createbulletin`}>
   <AddBulletin onAdd={addBulletin} />
</Route>```